# Python - AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a CSV file with various columns and everything worked perfectly for the past few months until I updated the file and got new information and now the one column does not appear to be picked up by Python. I am using Python 2.7 and have made sure I have the latest version of pandas.

When I downloaded the csv file from Yahoo Finance, I opened it in Excel and made changes to the format of the columns in order to make it more readable as all information was in one cell. I used the "Text to Column" feature and split up the data based on where the commas were.

Then I made sure that in each column there were no white spaces in the beginning of the cell using the Trim function in excel and left-aligning the data.

**I tried the following and still get the same or similiar:**

After the `df = pd.read_csv("KIO.csv")` I tried to read whether I can read the first few columns by using `df.head()` - but still got the same error.

I tried renaming the problematic column as suggested in a similiar post using:
`df = df.rename(columns={"Close": "Closing"})` - here I got the same error again. "print df.columns" also led to the same issue.

"`df[1]`" - gave a long error with "KeyError: 1" at the end - I can print the entire thing if it it will assist.

Adding the "`skipinitialspace=True`" - no difference.

I thought the problem might be within the actual csv file information so I deleted all the columns and made my own information and I still got the same error.

Below is a portion of my code as the total code is very long:

```
enter code here
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as pltdate
import datetime
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("KIO.csv", skipinitialspace=True)
#df.head()

#Close = df.columns[0]
#df= df.rename(columns={"Close": "Closing"})
df1 = pd.read_csv("USD-ZAR.csv")

kio_close = pd.DataFrame(df.Close)
exchange = pd.DataFrame(df1.Value)
dates = df["Date"]
dates1 = df1["Date"]
```

The above variables have been used throughout the remaining code though so if this issue can be solved here the remaining code will be right.

This is copy/paste of the error:

> Blockquote
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/User/Documents/PycharmProjects/Trading_GUI/GUI_testing.py", line 33, in 
>       kio_close = pd.DataFrame(df.Close)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4372, in **getattr**
>       return object.**getattribute**(self, name)
>   AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Close'

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Show us the error message as it is .

Comment: I will edit above and include the error as is.

Comment: Opening .csv in Excel is should be forbidden(*). Excel tries to "gauge" the datatypes and converts stuff silently behind the scene - if you save the csv again you get modified values where you before had good data - expecially this happens with date-like values (i.e.  21.3 => 21st of March) etc. Make sure your data got not corrupted in that way and fashion.

Comment: (*) if you later save it as csv again and open it with other programs using this csv

Comment: I did not know that the data is changed behind the scenes in Excel. When I saved the csv file, it said that when saving it "may contain features that are not compatible with CSV". Does this mean that when I download a file from Yahoo Finance for example I am not allowed to alter it in any way in Excel? Why could I alter it previously in Excel but now all of a sudden it gives me these errors?

Comment: Ok - small update. If I do not make any changes to the csv file in excel it works fine. I tested this on a new script and using the original unadjusted csv data. However, sometimes csv files have information in them that I do not need and I am forced to make adjustments within them. However, once I save the file again these errors start popping up. Is there no work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rip_027 This is in regards to your last comment. I used to have the same issue whenever I open a csv file by simply double clicking the file icon. You need to launch Excel first, then get external data. Link below has more details,which will serve as a guideline. Hope this helps.

```
https://www.hesa.ac.uk/support/user-guides/import-csv
```

Comment: Thank you for this - sadly it doesn't seem to work for all csv files - one of the forex rates file I am using does not want to import into excel.